# Unknown Property and programatically adding textfields in Yii2 form

Tags: php, yii2

I am adding dynamic form field:

```
<?php
$channels = Channel::find()->all();

foreach ( $channels as $channel ) {
    $channel_name = 'channel_' . strtolower( $channel->name );
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <?= $form->field( $model, $channel_name )->textInput()->label( $channel->name ) ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I've declared it safe in the `rules()`:

```
$channels = Channel::find()->all();

foreach ( $channels as $channel ) {
    $rules[] = [['channel_' . $channel->name], 'safe'];
}

return $rules;
```

However I'm getting an error:

> Getting unknown property: app\models\MyModel::channel_facebook

How do I dynamically declare the `'channel_' . $channel->name` properties in Yii2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply override [`attributes()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#attributes()-detail), e.g. :

```
public function attributes()
{
    // just an example, not really efficient but it will work
    $attributes = [];
    $channels = Channel::find()->all(); 
    foreach ($channels as $channel) {
        $attributes[] = 'channel_' . strtolower($channel->name);
    }
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), $attributes);
}
```